# General error during canonicalization: Importing [java.text.SimpleDateFormat] is not allowed

Tags: groovy, bpmn

General error during canonicalization: Importing [java.text.SimpleDateFormat] is not allowed

java.lang.SecurityException: Importing [java.text.SimpleDateFormat] is not allowed

Comment: Using what? Which tool? What's the script?

Comment: BPMN diagram using activiti plugin
groovy scripting to parse the date
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
 SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy")
 DATE_FORMAT.toPattern()
 def date = new Date()
   DATE_FORMAT.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
   println(DATE_FORMAT.parse(DATE_FORMAT.format(date)).getTime())

Comment: Please take the time to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60665853/edit) the question.

Comment: Its groovy script to run the bpmn diagram
Below is the sample code
 import java.text.SimpleDateFormat SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy") DATE_FORMAT.toPattern() def date = new Date() DATE_FORMAT.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")) println(DATE_FORMAT.parse(DATE_FORMAT.format(date)).getTime())